# Javascript - Editing a class instead of ID not working / Editing the heigh of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well, I tried to make something with JavaScript, but it won't work. I played around with

```
document.getElementById('idhere').innerHTML('whateverhere');
```

and what not, and it worked fine.
Then I was going to edit an class using

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname').innerHTML('whateverhere');
```

but it wouldn't change anything. I tried multiple times but it just won't work.

Now, my second question is; I have multiple lines like those on a site (forum);

```
<div style="height:250px;overflow: auto;">
    <blockquote class="signature restore">
        <div class="signaturecontainer">
            <a href="HREFHERE" target="_blank">
                <img style="max-width: 595px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open(this.src)"  src="IMAGEHERE" border="0" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

And I would like to change the height because signatures are not showing up properly. (you have to scroll to see the whole signature(s). And as I want it not to be so, I want to change it, using it as a user script. It depends on how many posts on the thread how many

```
<div style="style here">
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements. You have to loop through the array and set the `innerHTML` on each element individually.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName returns a collection of elements. try document.getElementsByClassName('asd')[0].innerHTML("bla");

Comment: Didn't realize that it returns the array, lol. Now when I think of it, it makes sense. >.<

Comment: Do you want to re--implement standard JQuery functionality? Why? What is your goal? (Clearly not to change HTML - `$(".signature.restore").html("whaterverhere")` will do what you want and is much easier for most people to read/reason about as most never used native HTML APIs).

Comment: Thanks. Do anyone of you know how to fix the second one tho? The style one.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, if you got image(s) that is larger than X in height, it'll make it so you have to scroll through each signature to see them. I simply want to change the <div style='height:Xpx'> of each signature div so all images fit. :P

Comment: Please ask one question per post. I'm not sure how image height relates to usage of `getElementsByClassName`... or where you questions split...

Comment: What element-class are you selecting by, how do you want to change that/those element(s)?

Comment: @MikeW getElementsByClassName() returns `NodeList` (Chrome) or `HTMLCollection` (Firefox). Try `document.getElementsByClassName('class') instanceof Array` (will be `false`).

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like.
`innerHTML` isn't a function.

```
var i,
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].innerHTML = 'whateverhere';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to fix the second question I asked? :x
If you got image(s) that is larger than X in height, it'll make it so you have to scroll through each signature to see them. I simply want to change the <div style='height:Xpx'> of each signature div so all images fit. :P I don't know how to change the <div style> and I'm not sure how I would count all images in each signature div's either.

Comment: Hey, re-post your second question in another post. In addition, try to be clearer.

Comment: @WoopWoopWoopWoop, BTW, did you try to remove the `height` property style?

Comment: I tried to re-post but it says I have to wait X amount of time. :/
And well, no. I'm not sure how I remove it as the div is not having an id or class name. It looks like:

< div style='height:Xpx;overflow:scroll'>

Comment: I managed to fix so it sets the height etc. But how would I remove it?

Comment: getElementsByClassName() returns `NodeList` (Chrome) or `HTMLCollection` (Firefox). Try `elements instanceof Array` (will be `false`).

Comment: @Pavlo That's true, it's `array-like` (it has `length` property for example). It can use easily `Array` methods by `Array.prototype.slice.apply(elements, someArguments)`. Even be converted to array by `var NodeArray = Array.prototype.slice.apply(elements)`